# Exit button stays fixed to the right of screen when it shouldn't do

Tags: android

I am having a little design issue in my android. Basically I have three elements displayed horizontally next to each other.

Now the Title on the left hand side is perfect and starts of 10dp from the left and the logo is also perfect as diplayed in the center.

The problem is with the exit button as it is suppose to be set 10dp from the right margin but instead it says fixed right at the end of the margin. I seem to not be able to change it and it seems that the logo settings may have an impact on the exit button.

What is in my code that's causing this issue?

Thanks in advance:

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="10dp"
        android:paddingBottom="10dp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/footer_title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold"
            android:gravity="start"
            android:text="Tic Tac Toe "
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryLight"/>

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/footer_logo"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/mima_apps_logo"
            />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/button_exit"
            android:layout_width="51dp"
            android:layout_height="27dp"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/app_buttons"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Exit"
            android:textSize="10sp"
            android:textColor="@color/black"
            android:fontFamily="@font/balloon_extra_bold" />

    </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Try `android:padding="10dp"` on the `RelativeLayout` and remove other paddings.

Comment: omg you put it like that and it's so simple. Thank you

Comment: you're welcome. Also you won't need margin attributes on views inside `RelativeLayout`. Happy coding